# C# Change downloaded file directory

Tags: c#, streamwriter, bufferedstream

I have the following code where it will retrieve data from `stream` and print it to text file using `streamwriter` and bufferedwriter. By default, it will download the file to the download folder directory in your local pc. The issue that I’m facing right now is I would like to change the directory of the downloaded file to some other directory but I was unable to achieve those. Instead I use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` to achieve those but that’s not what I want since the code below will download two files, one in download folder and another in document folder.

```
protected override void AddPlainText(Stream outputStream)
{
    var records = GetData();
    var x = new StringBuilder();
    string stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy_HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string fileName = "reportTxt_" + stamp + ".txt";
    string path = @"C://Users//***//Documents//";
    string path2 = @"C:\Users\***\Documents\";

    using (var stream = new BufferedStream(outputStream))
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII);

        foreach (var r in records)
        {
            x.AppendLine(r.ToFixedLengthString());
        }
        var output = x.ToString();
        writer.WriteLine(output);
        writer.Flush();

        //Create File
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + fileName, output);

        //Calling Transfer Method
        SFTP_Connection(fileName, path2);

        //Delete file after transfer
        if (File.Exists(path + fileName))
        {
            File.Delete(path + fileName);
        }
    }
 }
```

Any advice, tips and help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why the file has to be saved to `path`, then copied from `path` to `path2`? Cannot it be saved to `path2` directly?

Comment: @kennyzx Its basically for SFTP Connection where the directory does not recognize "/" but instead it recognize "\"

Comment: Still there are some things to clarify. 1. `SFTP_Connection` transfers the file in the document folder to a remote place, right? 2. "one in download folder and another in document folder", you mean another file is created in _Downloads_? 3. What is the parameter `outputStream` and how is it created?

Comment: @kennyzx Yes you are right to all. Without System.IO.File.WriteAllText code, the code will still create the txt file but will be placed at the download folder by default. Even if I use filestream, it will create another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I think you may have mistakenly assume the data is **read from** the stream, in fact, in the code snippet, the stream is used to be **written to**.

First, data is retrieved from this call

```
var records = GetData();
```

And then the data is converted to a string, and the string is written to the `BufferedStream` using a `StreamWriter`, and finally written to the `outputStream`.

(`BufferedStream` is used as a buffer - thus the name 'BufferedStream' - in order to boost performance of the write operation.)

So one possibility is that the `outputStream` is a `FileStream` created by the caller, and it is created in the *Downloads* folder.

If this is the case, you don't need to pass the `outputStream`, in fact, don't create it in the first place!

After removing the unnecessary streams, this is all you need

```
var records = GetData();
var x = new StringBuilder();
string stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy_HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string fileName = "reportTxt_" + stamp + ".txt";
string path = @"C://Users//***//Documents//";
string path2 = @"C:\Users\***\Documents\";
foreach (var r in records)
{
    x.AppendLine(r.ToFixedLengthString());
}
//Create File
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + fileName, output);

//Calling Transfer Method
SFTP_Connection(fileName, path2);

//Delete file after transfer
if (File.Exists(path + fileName))
{
    File.Delete(path + fileName);
}
```

Another possibility is the call `SFTP_Connection` creates an intermediate file in the *Downloads* folder. Check the implementation of the call for sure.

You need to step into (F10/F11) the code to check at which line the unwanted file is created.